# JMeter SocketTimeout and OutofMemoryErrors

Tags: jmeter, out-of-memory, socket-timeout-exception

I have the following code in JSR223 Sampler and I get following errors when I run this jmeter command. Can anyone please advise if something is wrong with my code? I'm basically reading a image and changing it little bit and sending a multipart/form-data POST request.

jmeter -n -Jthreads=20 -Jrampup=30 -Jduration=60 -Jiterations=-1 -t script.jmx

javax.script.ScriptException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-10,5,main]

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

import java.security.cert.CertificateException
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate

List<String> sendRequest(String url, String method, String body) {


RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(2000)
        .setSocketTimeout(3000)
        .build();

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/bd3249/Pictures/5.JPG"));
Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
graphics.setFont(graphics.getFont().deriveFont(16f));
graphics.drawString("User " + ctx.getThreadNum() + '-' + Math.random()  +"; iteration: " + ctx.getVariables().getIteration(), 50, 50);
graphics.dispose();
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", bytes);

final MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("File", bytes.toByteArray(),ContentType.IMAGE_JPEG, "5.JPG");


HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create(method)
        .setConfig(requestConfig)
        .setUri(url)
        .setHeader("x-ibm-client-id","248a20f3-c39b-45d0-b26a-9019c26e9be8")
        .setHeader("X-Client-Id","2861D410-773B-4DD9-AE74-882116B08856")
        .setEntity(multipartEntity.build())
        .build();

String req = "REQUEST:" + "User " + ctx.getThreadNum() + "; iteration: " + ctx.getVariables().getIteration() + " " + request.getRequestLine() + "\n";

def builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        return true;
    }
});
def trustAllFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(), new NoopHostnameVerifier());

HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(trustAllFactory).build().withCloseable { httpClient ->

    httpClient.execute(request).withCloseable { response ->

        String res = "RESPONSE:" + "User " + ctx.getThreadNum() + "; iteration: " + ctx.getVariables().getIteration() + " " + response.getStatusLine()  + (response.getEntity() != null ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : "") + "\n";

        log.info(req + "\n" + res);

        return Arrays.asList(req, res);
    }
  }
}

List test1 = sendRequest("https://test.com/upload", "POST", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting clearly indicates that you don't have sufficient [Java Heap space](https://www.azul.com/resources/azul-technology/what-is-java-heap-size/), by default [JMeter 5.3](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/JMeter-User-f512775.html) comes with 1 GB of heap and depending on your image size and response size it might be not enough for your test.

Use i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener to see how many virtual users were online when the error occurs and increase the heap size proportionally.

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)